# Move bits of panoramic background horizontally upon scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

In Swift 5, how do I create a scrollable panoramic background image from left to right and vice versa?

I imagine it having a wide panoramic picture with several buttons, dividing and showing the background in parts, allowing it to be scrolled horizontally.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to add then in a scrollView and make horizantal scroll enable by making its content size like

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 300)
```

Add your views in this scrollview

make scrollView frame according to your screen size or on requirement

```
scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300)
```